# Ubuntu 12.04 - Workspace switcher is shown after switching to another workspace

Tags: 12.04, unity

I've just upgraded to Ubuntu 12.04 on HP Envy 14 and found a rather interesting bug.  When I switch between workspaces using keyboard shortcuts, for example moving down to Workspace 3 from Workspace 1, workspace switcher is shown (as seen on below screenshot). It stays there until I hit escape key.

After debugging, the problem only happens when I change shortcut keys to `Super` + `direction`. With default `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `direction`, everything is OK.

I've searched but haven't found this problem reported before, I'm also not sure this is called workspace switcher :) Can you please let me know what to search for, are there any logs which might have some related information?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this as follows..

1) Install ccsm

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

invoke on cmd line ccsm

2) disable unity keyboard shortcut, this is mapped to 'super' which seems to collide with the super- shortcut you are trying to create

In ccsm, under 'Ubuntu Unity Plugin', disable 'Key to show the launcher' and I also disabled 'Key to start the launcher application switcher' and 'Key to start the launcher application switcher in reverse'

cheers,
S

Comment: Works, thank you! Just wondering how long will it last until it's broken again :)